# Firebase Functions Failed to load function definition from source

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-tools

I am working on an existing React / Firebase project and wanted to add emulators, ironically to save time. I have not been able to get the emulators to run locally.

I get a rather vague error:

`⬢  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: There was an error reading functions/package.json:`

After spending several hours going through each line of code in the functions project I could not find any issues. It also deploys fine and works when I use:

`firebase deploy --only functions`

This also uses a strict linter so even unused vars fail to deploy.

In the end I created a brand new project using:

`npm create vite@latest my-app --template react`

I then install a fresh version of firebase and walked through the setup using:

`firebase init`

When I went to run the completely blank functions project (`firebase emulators:start`), I get the exact same bug.

I am using a Macbook Air M2, could this be a part of the problem? I am also running the `OpenJDK Runtime Environment` in place of Java.

Here is the log:

```
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.143Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.143Z] Command:       /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.1/bin/node /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.1/bin/firebase emulators:start
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.144Z] CLI Version:   12.7.0
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.144Z] Platform:      darwin
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.144Z] Node Version:  v18.16.1
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.145Z] Time:          Thu Oct 12 2023 16:26:17 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.145Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [debug] 
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.173Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.173Z] > authorizing via signed-in user (user@company.io)
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.202Z] openjdk version "21" 2023-09-19

  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.202Z] OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 21)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 21, mixed mode, sharing)

  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.205Z] Parsed Java major version: 21
  [info] i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, functions, firestore, hosting {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"hub"},"message":"Starting emulators: auth, functions, firestore, hosting"}}
  [warn] ⚠  hosting: The hosting emulator is configured but there is no hosting configuration. Have you run firebase init hosting? {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"hosting"},"message":"The hosting emulator is configured but there is no hosting configuration. Have you run \u001b[1mfirebase init hosting\u001b[22m?"}}
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.600Z] [logging] Logging Emulator only supports listening on one address (127.0.0.1). Not listening on ::1
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.601Z] [auth] Authentication Emulator only supports listening on one address (127.0.0.1). Not listening on ::1
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.601Z] [firestore] Firestore Emulator only supports listening on one address (127.0.0.1). Not listening on ::1
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.601Z] [firestore.websocket] websocket server for firestore only supports listening on one address (127.0.0.1). Not listening on ::1
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.601Z] assigned listening specs for emulators {"user":{"hub":[{"address":"127.0.0.1","family":"IPv4","port":4400},{"address":"::1","family":"IPv6","port":4400}],"ui":[{"address":"127.0.0.1","family":"IPv4","port":4000},{"address":"::1","family":"IPv6","port":4000}],"logging":[{"address":"127.0.0.1","family":"IPv4","port":4500}],"auth":[{"address":"127.0.0.1","family":"IPv4","port":9099}],"firestore":[{"address":"127.0.0.1","family":"IPv4","port":8080}],"firestore.websocket":[{"address":"127.0.0.1","family":"IPv4","port":9150}]},"metadata":{"message":"assigned listening specs for emulators"}}
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.603Z] [hub] writing locator at /var/folders/1s/5h_pyf855sx0w00kjdcnn6cr0000gn/T/hub-project-id.json
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.731Z] [functions] Functions Emulator only supports listening on one address (127.0.0.1). Not listening on ::1
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.732Z] [eventarc] Eventarc Emulator only supports listening on one address (127.0.0.1). Not listening on ::1
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.732Z] late-assigned ports for functions and eventarc emulators {"user":{"hub":[{"address":"127.0.0.1","family":"IPv4","port":4400},{"address":"::1","family":"IPv6","port":4400}],"ui":[{"address":"127.0.0.1","family":"IPv4","port":4000},{"address":"::1","family":"IPv6","port":4000}],"logging":[{"address":"127.0.0.1","family":"IPv4","port":4500}],"auth":[{"address":"127.0.0.1","family":"IPv4","port":9099}],"firestore":[{"address":"127.0.0.1","family":"IPv4","port":8080}],"firestore.websocket":[{"address":"127.0.0.1","family":"IPv4","port":9150}],"functions":[{"address":"127.0.0.1","family":"IPv4","port":5001}],"eventarc":[{"address":"127.0.0.1","family":"IPv4","port":9299}]},"metadata":{"message":"late-assigned ports for functions and eventarc emulators"}}
  [warn] ⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: database, hosting, pubsub, storage {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: \u001b[1mdatabase, hosting, pubsub, storage\u001b[22m"}}
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.732Z] defaultcredentials: writing to file /Users/user/.config/firebase/user_company_io_application_default_credentials.json
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.733Z] Setting GAC to /Users/user/.config/firebase/user_company_io_application_default_credentials.json {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"Setting GAC to /Users/user/.config/firebase/user_company_io_application_default_credentials.json"}}
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:17.734Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/project-id/adminSdkConfig [none]
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:18.184Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/project-id/adminSdkConfig 200
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:18.184Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/project-id/adminSdkConfig {"projectId":"project-id","databaseURL":"https://project-id.firebaseio.com","storageBucket":"project-id.appspot.com","locationId":"europe-west"}
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:18.196Z] Ignoring unsupported arg: auto_download {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Ignoring unsupported arg: auto_download"}}
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:18.197Z] Ignoring unsupported arg: single_project_mode_error {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Ignoring unsupported arg: single_project_mode_error"}}
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:18.197Z] Starting Firestore Emulator with command {"binary":"java","args":["-Dgoogle.cloud_firestore.debug_log_level=FINE","-Duser.language=en","-jar","/Users/user/.cache/firebase/emulators/cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.18.2.jar","--host","127.0.0.1","--port",8080,"--websocket_port",9150,"--project_id","project-id","--rules","/Users/user/dev/firebase-test/firestore.rules","--single_project_mode",true,"--functions_emulator","127.0.0.1:5001"],"optionalArgs":["port","webchannel_port","host","rules","websocket_port","functions_emulator","seed_from_export","project_id","single_project_mode"],"joinArgs":false} {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Starting Firestore Emulator with command {\"binary\":\"java\",\"args\":[\"-Dgoogle.cloud_firestore.debug_log_level=FINE\",\"-Duser.language=en\",\"-jar\",\"/Users/user/.cache/firebase/emulators/cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.18.2.jar\",\"--host\",\"127.0.0.1\",\"--port\",8080,\"--websocket_port\",9150,\"--project_id\",\"project-id\",\"--rules\",\"/Users/user/dev/firebase-test/firestore.rules\",\"--single_project_mode\",true,\"--functions_emulator\",\"127.0.0.1:5001\"],\"optionalArgs\":[\"port\",\"webchannel_port\",\"host\",\"rules\",\"websocket_port\",\"functions_emulator\",\"seed_from_export\",\"project_id\",\"single_project_mode\"],\"joinArgs\":false}"}}
  [info] i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Firestore Emulator logging to \u001b[1mfirestore-debug.log\u001b[22m"}}
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:18.647Z] Oct 12, 2023 4:26:18 PM com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.firestore.websocket.WebSocketServer start
  INFO: Started WebSocket server on ws://127.0.0.1:9150
  {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Oct 12, 2023 4:26:18 PM com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.firestore.websocket.WebSocketServer start\nINFO: Started WebSocket server on ws://127.0.0.1:9150\n"}}
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:18.660Z] API endpoint: http:// {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"API endpoint: http://"}}
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:18.660Z] 127.0.0.1:8080
  If you are using a library that supports the FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable, run:

    export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=127.0.0.1:8080

  Dev App Server is now running.

  {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"127.0.0.1:8080\nIf you are using a library that supports the FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable, run:\n\n   export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=127.0.0.1:8080\n\nDev App Server is now running.\n\n"}}
  [info] ✔  firestore: Firestore Emulator UI websocket is running on 9150. {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Firestore Emulator UI websocket is running on 9150."}}
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:21.247Z] Ignoring unsupported arg: auto_download {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"ui"},"message":"Ignoring unsupported arg: auto_download"}}
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:21.247Z] Ignoring unsupported arg: port {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"ui"},"message":"Ignoring unsupported arg: port"}}
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:21.247Z] Starting Emulator UI with command {"binary":"node","args":["/Users/user/.cache/firebase/emulators/ui-v1.11.7/server/server.js"],"optionalArgs":[],"joinArgs":false} {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"ui"},"message":"Starting Emulator UI with command {\"binary\":\"node\",\"args\":[\"/Users/user/.cache/firebase/emulators/ui-v1.11.7/server/server.js\"],\"optionalArgs\":[],\"joinArgs\":false}"}}
  [info] i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"ui"},"message":"Emulator UI logging to \u001b[1mui-debug.log\u001b[22m"}}
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:21.297Z] Web / API server started at 127.0.0.1:4000
  {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"ui"},"message":"Web / API server started at 127.0.0.1:4000\n"}}
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:21.298Z] Web / API server started at ::1:4000
  {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"ui"},"message":"Web / API server started at ::1:4000\n"}}
  [info] i  functions: Watching "/Users/user/dev/firebase-test/functions" for Cloud Functions... {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"Watching \"/Users/user/dev/firebase-test/functions\" for Cloud Functions..."}}
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:21.502Z] Validating nodejs source
  [debug] [2023-10-12T15:26:22.621Z] > [functions] package.json contents: {
    "name": "functions",
    "scripts": {
      "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
      "build": "tsc",
      "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
      "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
      "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
      "start": "npm run shell",
      "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
      "logs": "firebase functions:log"
    },
    "engines": {
      "node": "18"
    },
    "main": "lib/index.js",
    "dependencies": {
      "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
      "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
      "eslint": "^8.9.0",
      "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
      "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
      "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0",
      "typescript": "^4.9.0"
    },
    "private": true
  }
  [error] ⬢  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: There was an error reading functions/package.json:

  functions/lib/index.js does not exist, can't deploy Cloud Functions {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: There was an error reading functions/package.json:\n\n functions/lib/index.js does not exist, can't deploy Cloud Functions"}}
  [info] 
  ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
  │ i  View Emulator UI at http://127.0.0.1:4000/               │
  └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

  ┌────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
  │ Emulator       │ Host:Port                        │ View in Emulator UI             │
  ├────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
  │ Authentication │ 127.0.0.1:9099                   │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/auth      │
  ├────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
  │ Functions      │ 127.0.0.1:5001                   │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/functions │
  ├────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
  │ Firestore      │ 127.0.0.1:8080                   │ http://127.0.0.1:4000/firestore │
  ├────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
  │ Hosting        │ Failed to initialize (see above) │                                 │
  └────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
    Emulator Hub running at 127.0.0.1:4400
    Other reserved ports: 4500, 9150

  Issues? Report them at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues and attach the *-debug.log files.
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the logs you've provided, it seems that you're using TypeScript to write Functions. To be able to run this using the emulator, you need to compile it first to JavaScript.

I was able to successfully run the template using the steps below:

- Open a terminal and run command `npm create vite@latest my-app`
- Select **React** for the framework and **TypeScript** for the variant
- Install Firebase: run command `npm install firebase` inside `my-app` directory
- Set up Firebase project and products: run command `firebase init` inside `my-app` directory
- Select Firebase project, products and emulators
- Under `functions` directory, uncomment the sample `helloWorld` function inside `index.ts` file
- Under `functions` directory, run command `npm run build` to build the app and compile your code into JavaScript. To verify, you should see the `index.js` file under `functions/lib` directory
- Start the emulator: under `my-app` directory run command `firebase:emulators start --only functions`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I followed these steps and still get "⬢  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error". Are you on M2 and running OpenJDK? I am wondering if that might be the issue?

Comment: I'm using i7. If you're still getting the same error, I suggest you reach out to Firebase support or create an issue on Firebase Tools CLI GitHub repository.

Comment: We're using the same version of node. I just updated the last two steps. Could you try again?

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I will have to revisit the code

Comment: Thank you @looptheloop88 for the help. I didn't know I needed to compile first to JavaScript.